# Redirecting output to file in python

Tags: python

In shell script if we have sth like :

```
field1 = 22
qry="delete from table_name where id = $field1
echo $qry >> /tmp/query.ksh
```

Here in the file we have

```
delete from table_name where id = 22
```

I want to achieve the same in python

How should I achieve this in python
I am doing

```
fo = open("file","a")
fo.write(qry)
```

But this is not working.

Please suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like what you already have should work fine.

```
   field1 = 22
   qry = "delete from table_name where id = {0}\n".format(field1)
   with open('your_file', 'a') as f:
     f.write(qry)
```

what is specifically not working? where is all your python code? you posted only 2 lines where are you defining `qry`?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is correct assuming you want to append to a file named `file`.

Note that you should close the files that you open or (on recent Python versions) use `with` statements. Translating your shell code to Python,

```
field1 = 22
qry = "delete from table_name where id = {}".format(field1)
with open('/tmp/query.ksh', 'a') as of:
    of.write(qry)
```

Note that in real life you should not directly insert data into prepared SQL statements, because it can possibly lead to SQL injections.

Comment: @Lev... This is working fine but in file I am getting delete from table_name where id = {22}
But I want it like 
delete from table_name where id = 22
Please tell me how this can be acheived.
Thanks !!!

Comment: change in "where id = %d" % field1, if it's always an int

Comment: @KundanKumar Strange. Is it Python 2.6? On Python 2.7 it works fine. Can you try `{0}` instead of `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, alternatively 
you can direct print output to file by doing this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("file","a")

field1 = 22
qry = "delete from table_name where id = {0}\n".format(field1)
print qry
```